# INSERT inside plsql procedure does not tell how many rows were inserted

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

i am trying to insert some rows and update some rows inside a pl/sql  loop.

however  all i get to see is the pl/sql procedure is successfully completed.

i do get to see dbmbs_ouput statements but not the output status of insert and/or update queries.

the serveroutput is set to on.

how do i get to see the status of insert and update rows(namely how many rows were inserted and updated)

Comment: Is the loop encountering an error, or are you trapping/handling the error(s)?  When is a COMMIT made -- if after the loop, then none were successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, the `rowcount` is not output automatically like it is in `SQL Server`.

You should do it explicitly:

```
BEGIN
        INSERT
        INTO    mytable
        SELECT  …
        FROM    other_table;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SQL%ROWCOUNT);
END;
```

Comment: And note that SQL%ROWCOUNT is reset to zero after a COMMIT or ROLLBACK, so it's best to put that line immediately after the DML statement.

Comment: @Jeffrey: actually, that's what I was trying to show putting the semicolon after the ellipsis :)

Comment: so if i have multiple inserts and delete the rowcount gives me the rows effected by the latest dml statement?