# SQLPLUS Doesn't print number of rows affected

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Im executing below Script in a .sql file. I'm using Windows Command line console to invoke sqlplus. When script terminates everything looks good, except that I couldn't see number of records added by the INSERT statement. You can see the Output also below:

**SCRIPT**

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
SET FEEDBACK  ON 
SET VERIFY ON
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output Nothing');
END;
/
INSERT INTO .........

COMMIT;
QUIT;
/
```

**OUTPUT DISPLAYED**

```
SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Apr 9 22:08:47 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Commit complete.

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64
bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
```

When I execute the same SQL on a tool like TOAD/SQLNavigator, I could see the number of rows added (See ** marked line below).

**OUTPUTDISPLAYED ON TOAD**

```
Processing ...
SET FEEDBACK  ON 

SQL*Plus command ignored.
Processing ...
SET VERIFY ON


SQL*Plus command ignored.
Processing ...
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Doing Nothing');
END;

Doing Nothing
Processing ...
INSERT INTO .......

**11 row(s) inserted**

Processing ...
COMMIT

Processing ...
QUIT;

SQL*Plus command ignored.
```

Can you tell me which setting probably will help me geting numbers of rows impacted by this SQL, even when I run this script through simple `'sqlplus'`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSERT inside plsql procedure does not tell how many rows were inserted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139945/insert-inside-plsql-procedure-does-not-tell-how-many-rows-were-inserted)

Comment: Doesn't appear that the INSERT is inside a pl/sql block, however.

Answer (score 3):

SQL*Plus doesn't ouput the row count but you can do it explicitly with something like:

```
INSERT blah blah blah;
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQL%ROWCOUNT);
```

Answer (score 3):

The default threshold for SET FEEDBACK ON is 6. If you want feedback on a fewer number, use "SET FEEDBACK 1".

Comment: This made no difference for me.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
set echo on
set autotrace on
```

which  display the command executed and statistics about the statement in this case the number of rows inserted

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
SET FEEDBACK  ON 
SET VERIFY ON
set echo on
set autotrace on
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output Nothing');
END;
/
INSERT INTO .........

COMMIT;

QUIT;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work for me with the 11g client:

```
C:\>sqlplus user/pw

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Apr 9 21:12:12 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> insert into testing (select 1,'XX' from dual connect by level < 11);

10 rows created.

SQL>
```

I didn't think the 10g client worked differently, but I can't test it right now.

EDIT:

Works the same with 10g SQLPlus. I ran your exact script today:

```
C:\>sqlplus user/pw@db

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Tue Apr 10 09:12:26 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

DB> WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
DB> WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 1 ROLLBACK
DB> SET FEEDBACK  ON
DB> SET VERIFY ON
DB> BEGIN
  2      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output Nothing');
  3  END;
  4  /
Output Nothing

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

DB> insert into xx (select 'AA' from dual connect by level < 10);

9 rows created.

DB> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

DB> QUIT;
Disconnected from Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

C:\>
```

It doesn't matter if I insert 1 row or 9. I get the message. I am guessing there's something you're leaving out of your script example. Is the INSERT inside a BEGIN/END block? That would suppress the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
rem to see Pl/SQL "print" statements:
set serveroutput on
```